# I cant create a VM on azure using spot instance

Tags: azure

I am getting this error even using a template that was available in the region. I am using Standard_D4_v3. **The template deployment failed with error: 'The resource with id: '/subscriptions/32cc2407-71f3-4d35-9c3b-d3a2573f18ec/resourceGroups/clt/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm' failed validation with message: 'The requested size for resource '/subscriptions/32cc2407-71f3-4d35-9c3b-d3a2573f18ec/resourceGroups/clt/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm' is currently not available in location 'southeastasia' zones '' for subscription '32cc2407-71f3-4d35-9c3b-d3a2573f18ec'. Please try another size or deploy to a different location or zones. See https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.'.'.**

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the link in the error it tells you what this means if you are using spot VMS:

> If you are deploying an Azure Spot VM or Spot scale set instance,
>   there isn't any capacity for Azure Spot in this location. For more
>   information, see Spot error messages.

So, looks like there is no spot capacity for this VM, in that region, at the spot price you have asked for.